# Table on Azure-SQL larger than expected

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have a table on an Azure-SQL database that is growing much faster than expected.

The table has the following columns:

```
id PK INT
fk_id1 FK INT
fk_id2 FK INT
fk_id3 FK INT
vc_field1 VARCHAR(100)
vc_field2 VARCHAR(15)
bit_field1 BIT
dt_field1 DATETIME
```

The table has just over 20000 rows and the size of the table is about 1 GB with two foreign key indexes in the 300 MB range.  Based on the size of tables that are similar in field size and row count I would expect to see a table size of just a couple of MB (less that 50 MB).  Any thoughts or help in this regard would be much appreciated.  The nature of this table is that I only ever do inserts into the table.  No need for updates or deletes.

Comment: Did you try shrinking the database? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/file-space-manage#reclaim-unused-allocated-space

Comment: Yes. No luck though.

Comment: Is your problem with the database file, or the log file? Even if you only have 20K inserts only, you may have thousands of selects over that table.

Comment: It looks like the DB file.